# Shortest subset for given sum and fastest solution in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a variant of ["given sum problem"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html) and I try to write a solution in *Python* which will solve it in `O(log n)` time. For a given natural number `N` `(equal or larger than 1)` find the shortest count of items `p`<sub>`1..n`</sub> which sum makes the `N`, and `p` items are a product of below *iteration*:

value of `p`<sub>`i`</sub> is either `p`<sub>`i-1`</sub>`* 2` or`p`<sub>`i-1`</sub>`+ 1`

start from `p`<sub>`1`</sub> which is exactly 1

so accordingly:

`p`<sub>`2`</sub> is always 2, but `p`<sub>`3`</sub> can be either 3 or 4

For the input `N = 18`, candidate sets are: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 8], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]

And the `answer is 5`.

This is code I wrote so far but it's slow and freezes on moderately "big" (N >= 1000) values:

```
possible = None


def solution(N):
    global possible
    possible = list()
    tea(1, [1], N)
    sizes = [len(p) for p in possible]
    return min(sizes)
    pass


def tea(n, l, target):
    global possible
    if (sum(l) > target):
        return
    elif (sum(l) == target):
        possible.append(l)
    i = n * 2
    tea(i, l + [i], target)
    i = n + 1
    tea(i, l + [i], target)

print solution(18)
# should print 5
print solution(220)
# should print 11
print solution(221)
# no such solution? print -1
```

How to solve it in a more efficient way?

Fastest solutions are most crucial but a more *pythonic* code is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use breadth-first search to reduce wasted effort. The code below could be optimized more.

```
def solution(n):
    q = [(1,)]
    visited = set()
    for seq in q:
        s = sum(seq)
        if s == n:
            return seq
        elif s > n:
            continue
        key = (seq[-1], s)
        if key in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(key)
        q.append(seq + (seq[-1] * 2,))
        q.append(seq + (seq[-1] + 1,))
    return None
```

Comment: I think you want to return `-1` instead of `None` when there is no solution

Comment: @Elisha Perhaps, but that's less Pythonic.

Comment: I agree, but this is what the OP asked. However, this is not very important for the question, your answer is very good

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the shortest solution, so if you found a solution, there is no need to look for longer ones.
you can change the code so it will not look for solutions longer then what you have found this way:
(note the added if condition)

```
def tea(n, l, target):
    global possible
    if (sum(l) > target):
        return
    elif (sum(l) == target):
        possible.append(l)

    # we want to keep looking for new solutions only if l is shorter!
    if possible and (len(l) >= max(len(i) for i in possible)):
        return

    i = n * 2
    tea(i, l + [i], target)
    i = n + 1
    tea(i, l + [i], target)
```

in addition, seems like you want the function to return `-1` when there is no solution, currently, your code will raise an error on such cases, I would change `solution()` funtion to this:

```
possible = []

def solution(N):
    global possible
    tea(1, [1], N)
    sizes = [len(p) for p in possible] # you can use: size = map(len,possible) instead
    if sizes:
        return min(sizes)
    return -1
```

and as for your "more *pythonic* code", I would write it this way:

```
def solution(N):
    possibles =[]
    tea(1, [1], N, possibles)
    if not possibles:
        return -1
    else:
        return min(map(len,possibles))

def tea(n, l, target, possibles): # maybe a better name then "tea"
    if (sum(l) > target):
        return
    elif (sum(l) == target):
        possibles.append(l)
        return
    if possibles and (len(l) >= max(len(i) for i in possibles)):
        return
    tea(n * 2, l + [n * 2], target, possibles)
    tea(n + 1, l + [n + 1], target, possibles)
```